# How can I make my guild icon in an EMBED more detailed in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I recently discovered how to get the guild's icon URL to put it into an EMBED, but it looks horrible (far too smooth). I tried the `dynamic` issue from discord.js, but it did not work. Here is my code :

```
@PraingloBot.command(aliases=['latency', 'latence'])
async def ping(ctx):

    await ctx.message.delete()

    avant = time.monotonic()
    calcul = await ctx.send("<:PraingloBot:901217139028017163> Calcul du ping en cours...")
    lag = round((time.monotonic()-avant) * 1000)

    await calcul.delete()

    embedping = Embed(colour=Colour(6653959))
    embedping.add_field(
        name="Ping",
        value=f'{round(PraingloBot.latency * 1000)} ms', inline=False
    )
    embedping.add_field(
        name="Latence API",
        value=f'{lag} ms', inline=False
    )
    embedping.set_author(
        name='Système de ping',
        icon_url=ctx.guild.icon_url
    )

    await ctx.send(embed=embedping)
```

Comment: Is this a `.py` or `.js` question, as you tagged `discord.py` but mention `discord.js`? Do you also have a picture showing us what you mean with "Far too smooth"? You can put images/urls into `embed.set_author`, `embed.set_image` or into `embed.set_thumbnail`

Comment: the code and the question you asked are not even related, now depends what "far too smooth" means for you, for the best quality of the image i would recommend to use .set_image because it's not resized

Comment: It's a ``.py`` question, and I mentionned ``discord.js`` because some features from ``js`` are in ``py`` so I was wondering if that one was. Also, it's ``embed.set_author`` that smoothes the icon too much ; here's an [example](https://i.postimg.cc/KvWRJqqj/Prainglo-Bot-image-too-smoothed.png) of one of my EMBEDS and the difference with the ``embed.set_image`` :

Comment: Could you add a picture of the result you currently have, and more details on what it should be instead ?

Comment: [Here](https://i.postimg.cc/wvRvMvt9/Prainglo-Bot-image-too-smoothed.png) are the 2 results.